# 64 bit linking of an object file

Tags: delphi, linker, 64-bit, java-native-interface

I am developing JNI DLL files in Delphi 7. The resulting files will be 32 bit DLLs, which do not work on a 64bit Java VM.

Delphi 7 has the possibility to generate **c** or **c++** object files. Is it possible to create a 64bit DLL from these object files with a third party linker?

Comment: If you don't mind changing how your delphi code talks to the Java code, perhaps you could create a network interface between them, and put the Delphi code in its own REST server, that runs as a CGI process. Then you can have 32 bit code talk to 64 bit java code easily, because they are in separate processes, and only connected by a socket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Delphi compiler emits 32 bit object code.  It doesn't matter how you slice it, that code cannot be linked into a 64 bit module.

At the moment your best bet is to use [FreePascal](http://freepascal.org/) which can produce 64 bit DLLs.  There is an upcoming 64 bit version of Delphi but its release date is unknown.

Another option would be to enforce the use of the 32 bit version of the JVM, if that is possible for you.

Comment: I did not dismiss the idea because the STDCALL interface is fixed in both cases. I think a minimal compatibility layer could create a 32 bit segment and a wrapper around the exported functions. But this is just speculation.

Comment: @vbence - The calling convention is actually different on Win32 and Win64. However, you are right that it is technically possible to write a bridge between 32-bit and 64-bit code (see http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27667).

Comment: @PhiS That's just two processes and some IPC.

Comment: True; I wasn't trying to suggest anything else, but given vbence's comment, I thought s/he might still be interested in it.

Answer (score 3):

No. 64 bit code is very different from 32 bit code, beyond simply using 64 bit instructions. MS introduced much stricter rules in parameter passing, stack data and alignment and so on. Really no way to include 32 bit code in a 64 bit DLL (and due to this is forbidden too to call 32 bit code from 64 bit one, and viceversa, but using specific techniques). You have to wait for the Delphi 64 bit compiler (and hope its first release is good enough), or look elsewhere. Delphi 7 is getting outdated anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I know it is outdated, but I am subscribing to an "if not broken don't fix it" approach concerning this component.

Comment: @vbence If you don't want to change the Pascal code then use a 32 bit JVM